# Managing another user's systemd units

Tags: sudo, systemd

Can one user, or maybe root, control another user's user level systemd services?

I've tried `sudo -u <some user> systemctl --user restart <some service>`, but it complains about dbus: `Failed to get D-Bus connection: Connection refused`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem when I remotely logged into my gentoo box via ssh. In my case this was because the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` and `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variables were missing. Run the following commands and try again:

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$UID"
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus"
```

If this helps, you can put those commands into your .bashrc. I guess there must be a more elegant solution than .bashrc but that depends on your distro.

[Here is where I found that solution.](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1570036#p1570036)

Edit:

logged in as root, I managed to successfully run `systemctl --user` as another user using `su` as follows:

```
su -c 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$UID" DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus" systemctl --user status' username
```

or using `sudo` (note, I had to explicitely add the respective users UID (1000) to the path '/run/user/', but if you are running it from a bash script you can use $SUDO_UID instead):

```
sudo -u username XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000" DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus" systemctl --user status
```

Comment: I have exactly that in `/etc/profile.d/dbus.sh`. I guess `sudo` needs those whitelisted, because it clears the environment by default. I'm not sure if it will just transfer the current user's runtime dir, though.

Answer (score 4):

**systemd 248** (released March 2021) introduced support for the syntax `-M username@` for specifying another user.

Assuming the other username is *testuser* and the service is *foobar.service*, you can now run

```
sudo systemctl -M testuser@ --user restart foobar.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `someuser` uses *bash* as their login shell, add the following *exports* to `~someuser/.bashrc`:

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$UID"
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus"
```

Then, a user with root/*sudo* privileges can interact with `someuser`'s systemd by wrapping the command with `runuser`:

```
sudo runuser -l someuser -c "systemctl --user restart some-template@$some-service.service"
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error (`Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`) when running the following command on Ubuntu 20.04:

`systemctl --user mask tracker-store.service tracker-miner-fs.service tracker-miner-rss.service tracker-extract.service tracker-miner-apps.service tracker-writeback.service`

The problem was because of the alias:

`alias systemctl='sudo systemctl'`

It substituted the `systemctl` with `sudo systemctl` and sudo caused the error.

The env vars:

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$UID"
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus"
```

are not used because of `sudo`.

`mkaito` wrote in [the comment above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245866/585416):

> I guess sudo needs those whitelisted, because it clears the environment by default.